# I have function calling anther function to return string, but I get undefined. because of the read file implement first

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, debugging, javascript-objects

I'm not that expert, but I can handle it:
this calling the function **checkTLS**

```js
// params={ibmdev_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_ssl: 'not imp'}  

Object.keys(params).forEach( key => {
    console.log(key);
    if(key.includes("tls")){ 
        //splitting parms to get cluster id
        clusterId=key.substring(0, key.indexOf("_"));
        console.log("cluster ID=="+clusterId);
        tlsresualt= checkTLS(clusterId);
        console.log("tls resualt is="+ tlsresualt);
        req.body[`${clusterId}_tls`]=tlsresualt;
        console.log(req.body.ibmdev_tls);
        console.log("==================================");
    }
});
```

The **checktlsStatus** is what I need to pass:

```js
function checkTLS(clusterID){
    fs.readFile("clusterinfo/clusterinfo.json",(err, clusters) => {
        TlsVerion="TLS12";
        if(TlsVerion.includes("TLS12")){ 
            console.log(`TLs check status ------------------------ for ${clusterID}`);
            console.log(` TLs match the Secuity Baseline requirment for ${clusterID}`);
            checktlsStatus="implemented";
            //req.body.ibmdevtls=tlsStatus;
            //return console.log(checktlsStatur+ "check for tls successed");
            // req.body.(`${clusterID}`+`tls`)=tlsStatus;
            return checktlsStatus;
        }
    )};
}
```

I have tried await and asycn , also execSync(`sleep 20`);

Comment: nothing in your code is asyncrhonous, so, no need for await or async

Comment: And where and how do you define the TlsVersion variable that you use in the checkTLS() function?

Comment: your variable name you assign to is `tlsResualt` but you then subsequently "use" `tlsresualt` ...

Comment: I edit the code for your question about tlsVersion

Comment: I figure it out, if I make return outside the `fs.read`, will take it, but inside the `fs.read` not returned.

Comment: but what I want is inside the `fs.read`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback doesn't work that way!

Think about this:

```js
function foo(name, callback) {
  callback(name.length);
}

function bar() {
  const abc = foo("something", (n) => {
    return n + 10;
  });
  console.log(abc);
}

bar();
```

The `abc` will always undifined because foo has no return value!

The callback return value is omitted by `foo`.

This is how you think `fs.readFile` works. But it not work like that way!

---

There is someways to solve it:

1. Add a callback to `checkTLS` function.
2. Use `fs.readFileSync`.
3. (Recommand)Use `Promise`(async/await) API.

Let's do it:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
params={ibmdev_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_ssl: 'not imp'}  

Object.keys(params).forEach(async (key) => {
    console.log(key);
    if(key.includes("tls")){ 
        //splitting parms to get cluster id
        clusterId=key.substring(0, key.indexOf("_"));
        console.log("cluster ID=="+clusterId);
        // this changed
        const tlsresualt = await checkTLS(clusterId);
        console.log("tls resualt is="+ tlsresualt);
        // req.body[`${clusterId}_tls`]=tlsresualt;
        // console.log(req.body.ibmdev_tls);
        console.log("==================================");
    }
});

async function checkTLS(clusterID){
    const clusters = await fs.promises.readFile("clusterinfo/clusterinfo.json");
    TlsVerion="TLS12";
    if(TlsVerion.includes("TLS12")){ 
        console.log(`TLs check status ------------------------ for ${clusterID}`);
        console.log(` TLs match the Secuity Baseline requirment for ${clusterID}`);
        checktlsStatus="implemented";
        //req.body.ibmdevtls=tlsStatus;
        //return console.log(checktlsStatur+ "check for tls successed");
        // req.body.(`${clusterID}`+`tls`)=tlsStatus;
        return checktlsStatus;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to do. So just remake `checkTLS` to an async function.

---

I recommand use `fs.promises` and `async/await`, if you don't want it. Try this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

params={ibmdev_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_ssl: 'not imp'}  

Object.keys(params).forEach( key => {
    console.log(key);
    if(key.includes("tls")){ 
        //splitting parms to get cluster id
        clusterId=key.substring(0, key.indexOf("_"));
        console.log("cluster ID=="+clusterId);
        // this changed
        checkTLS(clusterId)
            .then(tlsresualt => {
                console.log("tls resualt is="+ tlsresualt);
                // req.body[`${clusterId}_tls`]=tlsresualt;
                // console.log(req.body.ibmdev_tls);
                console.log("==================================");
            });
    }
});

function checkTLS(clusterID){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.readFile("clusterinfo/clusterinfo.json",(err, clusters) => {
            TlsVerion="TLS12";
            if(TlsVerion.includes("TLS12")){ 
                console.log(`TLs check status ------------------------ for ${clusterID}`);
                console.log(` TLs match the Secuity Baseline requirment for ${clusterID}`);
                checktlsStatus="implemented";
                //req.body.ibmdevtls=tlsStatus;
                //return console.log(checktlsStatur+ "check for tls successed");
                // req.body.(`${clusterID}`+`tls`)=tlsStatus;
                resolve(checktlsStatus);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options

Comment: what I want is to check TLS version in node, then return if implemented to reflecte it to req.body.

Comment: I try your code, still `tls resualt is=undefined`

Comment: the read file to take clusterID and cluster token to login then check for tls

Comment: thank you, the problem gone.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not test locally. I edited it, and comment req variable. It should run just node it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code with same functionality using async and await. Contents variable has the read file's contents.

```
    const fs = require('fs')
    const util = require('util')`enter code here`
    const readFileContent = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
    const fetchFile = async (path,clusterID) => {
    const buff = await readFileContent(path)

    const contents = buff.toString()
    TlsVerion="TLS12";
    if(TlsVerion.includes("TLS12")){ 
          console.log(`TLs check status ------------------------ for ${clusterID}`);
          console.log(` TLs match the Secuity Baseline requirment for ${clusterID}`);
          checktlsStatus="implemented";
          return checktlsStatus;
      }
      console.log(`\nContents of the file :`)
    }
       

    async function neo(){
        params={ibmdev_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_tls: 'not imp',ibmqa_ssl: 'not imp'}  

        for (const property in params) {
            console.log(property);
            if(property.includes("tls")){ 
                //splitting parms to get cluster id
                clusterId=property.substring(0, property.indexOf("_"));
                console.log("cluster ID=="+clusterId);
                tlsresualt = await fetchFile('file.json',clusterId);
                console.log("tls resualt is="+ tlsresualt);
                console.log("==================================");
        }
        }
    }


    neo()
```

Reference from [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-operate-callback-based-fs-readfile-method-with-promises-in-node-js/). You may refer the same for detailed explanation

Comment: the file content in JSON format and I need it that way, but you have converted to string.

Comment: you may use buff.toJSON(), this should yield in json